# Intercept every array access

Tags: php

While working with legacy code, I'd like to monitor all accesses to a certain array (array is only using strings as keys), being it reading and writing accesses. Particularly, it would be nice to now which keys are used during the accesses.

Is there a fast and easy way to achieve this with PHP (language + ext. libs)?

Using "Find in files" in some code editor is not the best solution, since the process should be automated.

Comment: Create a custom class extending array and echo on item access. Then, change the type of your array to this custom class.

Comment: Thank you! That is a great idea. I used some example code for implementing ArrayAccess and inserted some logging code. What is the custom here at SO to provide the answer? Should I post my code as an answer and mark that as a solution? Seems dirty to me, rewarding my own answer...

Comment: I think it's a good idea to answer your own question. You will help other people with similar problem.

Comment: In fact it's encouraged: http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, this is a possible solution. I used the basic example from http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.arrayaccess.php and extended it by logging each access and providing a method to read the log. It's nothing special, but helped me tracking the different places where the script accessed my array.

```
class logging_array implements ArrayAccess
{
    private $container = array();
    private $access_log = array();

    public function offsetSet($offset, $value)
    {
        if (is_null($offset))
        {
            $this->container[] = $value;
        }
        else
        {
            $this->access_log[] = "SET: " . $offset;
            $this->container[$offset] = $value;
        }
    }

    public function offsetExists($offset)
    {
        return isset($this->container[$offset]);
    }

    public function offsetUnset($offset)
    {
        $this->access_log[] = "UNSET: " . $offset;
        unset($this->container[$offset]);
    }

    public function &offsetGet($offset)
    {
        $this->access_log[] = "GET: " . $offset . " (". (isset($this->container[$offset]) ? "key valid" : "key invalid") . ")";

        if (isset($this->container[$offset]))
        {
            $myref =& $this->container[$offset];
            return $myref;
        }
        else
        {
            return null;
        }
    }

    public function getLog()
    {
        return implode("<br>\n", $this->access_log);
    }
}
```